# Simple html code I'm having such a difficult time with

Tags: html, css

Okay seriously I feel so stupid for not being able to figure this out, I guess it's just Monday or something. Anyway I'm trying simply to make something like [this as well as the logic I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIEFv.jpg).

. So I wrote what's happening into a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6AvNM/)

for you all and hoping you can help.

I know that this is going to be one of those things that ends up making me feel so stupid but for some reason I cannot figure out what's wrong.

HTML5

```
        <div id="logo-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="Img" alt="Image"></li>
                <li><img src="Img" alt="Image"></li>
                <li><img src="Img" alt="Image"></li>
                <li><img src="Img" alt="Image"></li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
                <li><img src="Img" alt="Image"></li>
                <li><img src="Img" alt="Image"></li>
                <li><img src="Img" alt="Image"></li>
                <li><img src="Img" alt="Image"></li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
                <li><img src="Img" alt="Image"></li>
                <li><img src="Img" alt="Image"></li>
                <li><img src="Img" alt="Image"></li>
                <li><img src="Img" alt="Image"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS3

```
#logo-wrapper {
width: 70%;
margin: 2% auto;
background-color: #2CAD96;
}

#logo-wrapper ul {
margin: 2%;
float: left;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#logo-wrapper ul li {
list-style: none;
display: block;
margin: 2%;
}

#logo-wrapper ul li img{
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question...?

Comment: The fiddle works and it doesn't look totally messed up. What's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: It doesn't look correct to me, first of all my black background doesn't show up at all, and all my images are in a list not a block.

And my question is what am I doing wrong for my images to not block correctly.

Comment: @Tim yes it looks messed up. Have see the screenshot what OP expecting the results.

Comment: ul list are floating then logo-wrapper has no content.

Comment: Don't know what your exact situation is, but a grid system is EXACTLY what the doctor ordered here.

Comment: @patricksweeney Looks like an interview test to me, so my guess is that using a grid system would be frowned upon, though otherwise I agree 100%

Comment: @BrianDriscoll completely agree. If i was interviewing someone, I gave them that, I'd HOPE they would say "Can I use a grid?" - shows they know when to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: No, it's not an interview test, and what is a grid system?

Answer (score 0):

`ul` lists have a default padding so you'll probably want to remove that with `padding:0;`.
Also you set the width of your #logo-wrapper to a certain value, even though the images inside might not fit. So you can either scale the images using `width:100%;height:auto;` or not set a width on the wrapper.

Also you'll want to add `display:inline-block;` to the ul and li elements and give them a width 40% or so.

And finally put a padding not a margin on the #logo-wrapper.

Edit: here's the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6AvNM/9/ if you tweak it some more you'll get your squares sorted out :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to clear floats. In my demo I used `clearfix` class. Also you might want to set a width to `ul` and `li`. I set them to `46%` providing that you use margin `2%`. Also make sure you reset default paddings on UL and LI.

```
#logo-wrapper ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 2%;
    width: 46%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6AvNM/11/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fiddled around also a bit, the difference to the other posts is: mine is not resizing, you did not specify that. Also on @dfsq's solution, the images loose side-relation, however, nice one. (y)

I used mainly `display: inline-block` here to avoid clearing floats and giving the wrapper a height. Since this is static now, you either have to give all elements the right size to work (wrap automatically) or put a `<br>` where you want it to wrap.

```
* 
{
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#logo-wrapper 
{
width: 1000px;
margin: 2% auto;
background-color: black;
display:inline-block;
}

#logo-wrapper ul 
{
margin: 2%;
display:inline-block;
background-color: red;
padding: 0;
width : 450px;    
}

#logo-wrapper ul li 
{
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
margin: 2%;
}

#logo-wrapper ul li img 
{
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
}
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6AvNM/12/